# I'm converting a xml to text file using xslt 2. In the output text file I need to insert whitespace before a dynamically generating number

Tags: xslt

This should be of length 5 char. Eg:If the generated no. is 5 digits there is no need for white space to be inserted before that no. For 4 digit a single space ,for 3 ditit 2 space and then the no. for 2 digit 3 space and then the no. for single digit 4 spaces and then the no.

Comment: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_pad-string-to-length.html is an example of appending a number of characters, you seem to want to prepend them so you need to change the order of the sequence passed in to `string-join`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring('     ', string-length(yournumber) + 1), yournumber)"/>
```